# Unable to locate custom action using rosmsg with catkin

Tags: ros, action, catkin, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Hydro-Catkin, when we add a *custom.action* to *my_package*, although it is correctly generated and we can use it, it is not listed when using the *rosmsg list* command. And if we specify the package, *rosmsg show my_package/customAction*, it reports the following:

```
Unable to load msg [my_package/customAction]: Cannot locate message [customAction] in package [my_package] with paths [['my_workspace/src/my_package/msg']]
```

We already tried [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/60585/rosmsg-cant-find-message-in-my-catkin-workspace/), and we still have the same problem.

We have noticed that the action generated messages (customAction.msg, customActionGoal.msg, customGoal.msg, CustomActionFeedback.msg, etc.) are created in *my_workspace/devel/share/my_package/msg*, BUT the *rosmsg* tool searches them in  *my_workspace/src/my_package/msg*.

With rosbuild this didn't happen, because the generated messages of the action were placed along with the regular messages in *my_package/msg*.

Is this a *rosmsg* bug in catkin? Or which would be the correct way to locate and get information of a custom action in catkin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147586/unable-to-locate-custom-action-using-rosmsg-with-catkin/) by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 738 on 2014-04-02

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2014-04-02**:
I've run into the same issue this morning. My python code can't find the custom action messages either. The message files are generated under `my_workspace/devel/share/my_package/msg` as above, and the python files under  `my_workspace/devel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_package/msg` too.

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2014-04-02**:
I solved my version of this problem using this answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/64935/importerror-with-custom-action-in-python/

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2014-04-02**:
I had a python file the same name as my package, e.g. `my_workspace/src/my_package/scripts/my_package.py` and when I was doing the import it was loading this file, not the ones for the auto-generated action messages. rosmsg still does not find the message files, but my code works nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

<s>This looks like a environment setup problem.</s>

How do you setup your ROS environment? What does your .bashrc contain (ROS related)? Do you source the devel/setup.bash of your workspace?

**Edit:**

It seems it is indeed a bug. @Dirk Thomas has filed a report and submitted a patch (see comments below): https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/385

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) on 2014-04-02**:
I source my_workspace/devel/setup.bash in my .bashrc, and everything seems to work fine.
The problem is just with the custom action generated messages, which are no longer placed within the package, as it happened in Fuerte-Rosbuild, and then, rosmsg list/show can't find them.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-03**:
Aha, yes I can confirm this problem. Not sure if this is a known limitation of the devel space. @Dirk Thomas do you know?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-04-04**:
That is indeed a problem. I was able to reproduce it easily - seems like nobody noticed until now. I have created a ticket / pull request: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/385 It would be great if you could give it a try and confirm that it works for you.

**Comment by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) on 2014-04-06**:
Thanks @Dirk Thomas. We have tried the ticket. First, the 'rosmsg list' works, but it takes long to give the result (~15 seconds with a loaded ws). Second, the 'rosmsg show customAction' does not work yet, seems that the share-path fix in iterate_packages is needed also at least in get_msg_text.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-04-07**:
I have updated the PR to also fix "rosmsg show". Can you please also measure what the time for "rosmsg list" was before applying the change? The ticket already mentions that it is expected that the runtime might double.

**Comment by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) on 2014-04-07**:
"rosmsg show" works. Before the change, "rosmsg list" was instant. Now for me it goes from 10 to 30 sec, depending on the number of pkgs in the ws ("rosmsg show" takes double time, for list and show). As the problem was with custom actions only, maybe the /opt/ros/hydro/share/* paths can be skipped.